# CI-CD Azure devops for function app deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

My Function app Name:

```
 my_func_dev_app
```

Functions I have in my project

```
func_dev
func_prd
```

Push func_dev to my_func_dev_app

Push func_prd to my_func_prd_app

But It is pushing both func_dev and func_prd to my_func_de_app

My app folder structure

```
 (folder)myapp_function
 (folder)func_dev  --__init__.py
                   -- function.json
             
  (folder)func_prd  --__init__.py
                    -- function.json
  task.py
```

Multi stage Pipeline:

```
#pipelines1
trigger:
- '*'

stages:
- stage: 'Build'
  displayName: 'Build the web application'
  jobs: 
  - job: 'Build'
    displayName: 'Build job'
    pool:
      name: 'onprem_agent'

    steps:

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
        Contents: |
          **/*
          !.git/**
        OverWrite: true
        CleanTargetFolder: true
        TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: "Archive files"
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/myapp_function'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip'

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'myapp_function'


- stage: 'DEV_AZURE'
  displayName: 'Az DEV Deploy'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: |
    and
    (
      succeeded(),
      eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], variables['releaseBranchName'])
    )
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    environment: dev
    variables:
    - group: Release
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - download: current
            artifact: myapp_function
            displayName: Downloading artifacts
          
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: CI-CD
              appType: functionAppLinux
              appName: my_func_dev_app
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/myapp_function/*.zip'
              deployToSlotOrASE: true
              resourceGroupName: my-rg
              slotName: PRODUCTION
            displayName: 'Deploying dev'
```

How to fix? Push func_dev to my_func_dev_app and ignore func_prd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to fix? Push func_dev to my_func_dev_app and ignore func_prd

To solve this issue, you can package your two projects separately into zip.

In your ArchiveFiles task, you need to specify a specific project.

For example:

For **func_dev** project: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/myapp_function/func_dev`

```
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: "Archive files"
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/myapp_function/func_dev'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId)-func_dev.zip'
```

Then you can only package the project corresponding to the function app name.

If you want to deploy two projects to the corresponding function app in one pipeline at the same time, you could use the same method to separately package the two projects as zip.

Comment: I have same source files for different function app..Making separate package consumes more storage space as artifacts and takes longer time to build ..Any solution? to share same source files to different app services